# Deploying Node.js app to Heroku. Error NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error

Tags: node.js, meteor, heroku, github

I am deploying my node.js application on heroku but when i run my app it shows me Application error and when i check my logs file i found NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error

My package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "wework-1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "We Work Meteor, a job board and developer directory for Meteor specific work https://www.weworkmeteor.com",
  "main": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "= 4.5.0",
    "npm": "= 3.9.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "pretest": "npm run lint --silent"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/rohitchaudhary701/wework-1.git"
  }
}
```

My logs file is:

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  = 4.5.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   = 3.9.6

       Resolving node version = 4.5.0 via semver.io...
       Downloading and installing node 4.5.0...
       Resolving npm version = 3.9.6 via semver.io...
       Downloading and installing npm 3.9.6 (replacing version 2.15.9)...
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Build succeeded!
 !     This app may not specify any way to start a node process
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 12.7M
-----> Launching...
       Released v6
       https://whispering-cliffs-66861.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

App url is https://whispering-cliffs-66861.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 3):

From your logs:

> This app may not specify any way to start a node process

You probably need to do two things:

1. add `start` script in `package.json`
2. make sure you listen on the port in `process.env.PORT`

Take a look at this example:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-live-color

See package.json and the `start` script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
```

See:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-live-color/blob/master/package.json#L6

And see the port number initialization:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3338;
// ...
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

See:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-live-color/blob/master/server.js#L13
- https://github.com/rsp/node-live-color/blob/master/server.js#L46-L48

If you want easier deploy with Deploy to Heroku button then you may also need an `app.json` file:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-live-color/blob/master/app.json

But for manual deploys you should only need a `start` script in `package.json` so that you app could be started with `npm start` and your app needs to take the port to listen to from the `PORT` environment variable.

You can test it with locally running:

```
PORT=2255 npm start
```

and making sure that you can access your app on http://localhost:2255/ for this and any other port you specify. If you cannot start your app with the above command then your app is unlikely to run on Heroku. You could also have a Procfile presend but without it you should at least have `npm start` working, see:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to deploy a **Meteor** app to Heroku.

Heroku is not as integrated with Meteor as Galaxy is, or as Modulus / Xervo used to be.

Heroku will detect a node-like app, but you will need first to *convert* your Meteor app into a **Node.js app**, typically using `meteor build` command and uploading the resulting server bundle, or using some MUP thing.

A simple alternative is to use a 3rd party [Buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks), which will do the conversion for you once you upload your Meteor app to Heroku.

You will find plenty resources for that on the above link or here on SO.

See for example: [Heroku errors with Meteor 1.4.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752914/heroku-errors-with-meteor-1-4-1-1/40685487#40685487)

Note: the `NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error` line is a *setting*, not an actual error…

Answer (score 0):

What does your Procfile look like? Make sure you don't have web: node app.js in the Procfile. I had the same error and didn't need to use the Procfile. Once I removed it started working.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turned out i required a package that was not in my package.json (dependency), when I added it, the application started working.