# Error: Cannot find module 'node-linux-x64/package.json' - pushing to Heroku for first time

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I'm trying to push to Heroku for the first time but I'm getting the following error:

`Error: Cannot find module 'node-linux-x64/package.json'`

I've tried implementing solutions from these stackoverflow questions to no success. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60405554/unable-to-push-to-heroku-cannot-find-module-node-linux-x64-package-json) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687489/deploying-node-js-app-to-heroku-error-npm-config-loglevel-error) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo/16151707#16151707)

Here's the full log:

```
    Enumerating objects: 1109, done.
    Counting objects: 100% (1109/1109), done.
    Delta compression using up to 8 threads
    Compressing objects: 100% (1045/1045), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (1109/1109), 33.55 MiB | 924.00 KiB/s, done.
    Total 1109 (delta 334), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Node.js app detected
    remote:        
    remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
    remote:        
    remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
    remote:        NODE_ENV=production
    remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
    remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
    remote:        
    remote: -----> Installing binaries
    remote:        engines.node (package.json):  14.x
    remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   6.x
    remote:        
    remote:        Resolving node version 14.x...
    remote:        Downloading and installing node 14.5.0...
    remote:        Bootstrapping npm 6.x (replacing 6.14.5)...
    remote:        npm 6.x installed
    remote:        
    remote: -----> Installing dependencies
    remote:        Installing node modules
    remote:        
    remote:        > node@14.4.0 preinstall /tmp/build_b95d3fdd/node_modules/node
    remote:        > node installArchSpecificPackage
    remote:        
    remote:        /tmp/build_b95d3fdd/node_modules/.bin/node: 1: /tmp/build_b95d3fdd/node_modules/.bin/node: ����: not found
    remote:        /tmp/build_b95d3fdd/node_modules/.bin/node: 1: /tmp/build_b95d3fdd/node_modules/.bin/node: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
    remote:        internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033
    remote:          throw err;
    remote:          ^
    remote:        
    remote:        Error: Cannot find module 'node-linux-x64/package.json'
    remote:        Require stack:
    remote:        - /tmp/build_b95d3fdd/node_modules/node/installArchSpecificPackage.js
    remote:            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1030:15)
    remote:            at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:81:19)
    remote:            at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_b95d3fdd/node_modules/node-bin-setup/index.js:18:27)
    remote:            at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
    remote:            at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
    remote:            at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5) {
    remote:          code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    remote:          requireStack: [
    remote:            '/tmp/build_b95d3fdd/node_modules/node/installArchSpecificPackage.js'
    remote:          ]
    remote:        }
    remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
    remote:        npm ERR! node@14.4.0 preinstall: `node installArchSpecificPackage`
    remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
    remote:        npm ERR! 
    remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the node@14.4.0 preinstall script.
    remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    remote:        
    remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.AEViv/_logs/2020-07-21T21_21_11_043Z-debug.log
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Build failed
    remote:        
    remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
    remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
    remote:        
    remote:        Some possible problems:
    remote:        
    remote:        - A module may be missing from 'dependencies' in package.json
    remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#ensure-you-aren-t-relying-on-untracked-dependencies
    remote:        
    remote:        Love,
    remote:        Heroku
    remote:        
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote: 
    remote: !       Push rejected to lapwing.
    remote: 
    To https://git.heroku.com/lapwing.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/lapwing.git'
```

I'm unsure of what to do next. I don't seem to have an untracked dependency, uninstalled all global dependencies, and been through the entirety of the [Heroku troubleshooting guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys).

Here is my `package.json` and `package-lock.json` incase that's of use:

```
    {
      "name": "magnetic-leads",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.html",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "Alex Vale",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "graphql-request": "^2.0.0",
        "node": "^14.4.0",
        "node-darwin-x64": "^14.5.0",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
        "path": "^0.12.7"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": "14.x",
        "npm": "6.x"
      }
    }
```

```
    {
      "name": "magnetic-leads",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "lockfileVersion": 1,
      "requires": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "accepts": {
          "version": "1.3.7",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts/-/accepts-1.3.7.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-Il80Qs2WjYlJIBNzNkK6KYqlVMTbZLXgHx2oT0pU/fjRHyEp+PEfEPY0R3WCwAGVOtauxh1hOxNgIf5bv7dQpA==",
          "requires": {
            "mime-types": "~2.1.24",
            "negotiator": "0.6.2"
          }
        },
        "array-flatten": {
          "version": "1.1.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/array-flatten/-/array-flatten-1.1.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-ml9pkFGx5wczKPKgCJaLZOopVdI="
        },
        "body-parser": {
          "version": "1.19.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser/-/body-parser-1.19.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-dhEPs72UPbDnAQJ9ZKMNTP6ptJaionhP5cBb541nXPlW60Jepo9RV/a4fX4XWW9CuFNK22krhrj1+rgzifNCsw==",
          "requires": {
            "bytes": "3.1.0",
            "content-type": "~1.0.4",
            "debug": "2.6.9",
            "depd": "~1.1.2",
            "http-errors": "1.7.2",
            "iconv-lite": "0.4.24",
            "on-finished": "~2.3.0",
            "qs": "6.7.0",
            "raw-body": "2.4.0",
            "type-is": "~1.6.17"
          }
        },
        "bytes": {
          "version": "3.1.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/-/bytes-3.1.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-zauLjrfCG+xvoyaqLoV8bLVXXNGC4JqlxFCutSDWA6fJrTo2ZuvLYTqZ7aHBLZSMOopbzwv8f+wZcVzfVTI2Dg=="
        },
        "content-disposition": {
          "version": "0.5.3",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/content-disposition/-/content-disposition-0.5.3.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-ExO0774ikEObIAEV9kDo50o+79VCUdEB6n6lzKgGwupcVeRlhrj3qGAfwq8G6uBJjkqLrhT0qEYFcWng8z1z0g==",
          "requires": {
            "safe-buffer": "5.1.2"
          }
        },
        "content-type": {
          "version": "1.0.4",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/content-type/-/content-type-1.0.4.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-hIP3EEPs8tB9AT1L+NUqtwOAps4mk2Zob89MWXMHjHWg9milF/j4osnnQLXBCBFBk/tvIG/tUc9mOUJiPBhPXA=="
        },
        "cookie": {
          "version": "0.4.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/-/cookie-0.4.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-+Hp8fLp57wnUSt0tY0tHEXh4voZRDnoIrZPqlo3DPiI4y9lwg/jqx+1Om94/W6ZaPDOUbnjOt/99w66zk+l1Xg=="
        },
        "cookie-signature": {
          "version": "1.0.6",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/-/cookie-signature-1.0.6.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-4wOogrNCzD7oylE6eZmXNNqzriw="
        },
        "debug": {
          "version": "2.6.9",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-2.6.9.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-bC7ElrdJaJnPbAP+1EotYvqZsb3ecl5wi6Bfi6BJTUcNowp6cvspg0jXznRTKDjm/E7AdgFBVeAPVMNcKGsHMA==",
          "requires": {
            "ms": "2.0.0"
          }
        },
        "depd": {
          "version": "1.1.2",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/depd/-/depd-1.1.2.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-m81S4UwJd2PnSbJ0xDRu0uVgtak="
        },
        "destroy": {
          "version": "1.0.4",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/destroy/-/destroy-1.0.4.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-l4hXRCxEdJ5CBmE+N5RiBYJqvYA="
        },
        "ee-first": {
          "version": "1.1.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ee-first/-/ee-first-1.1.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-WQxhFWsK4vTwJVcyoViyZrxWsh0="
        },
        "encodeurl": {
          "version": "1.0.2",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/encodeurl/-/encodeurl-1.0.2.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-rT/0yG7C0CkyL1oCw6mmBslbP1k="
        },
        "escape-html": {
          "version": "1.0.3",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html/-/escape-html-1.0.3.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-Aljq5NPQwJdN4cFpGI7wBR0dGYg="
        },
        "etag": {
          "version": "1.8.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/etag/-/etag-1.8.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-Qa4u62XvpiJorr/qg6x9eSmbCIc="
        },
        "express": {
          "version": "4.17.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-4.17.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-mHJ9O79RqluphRrcw2X/GTh3k9tVv8YcoyY4Kkh4WDMUYKRZUq0h1o0w2rrrxBqM7VoeUVqgb27xlEMXTnYt4g==",
          "requires": {
            "accepts": "~1.3.7",
            "array-flatten": "1.1.1",
            "body-parser": "1.19.0",
            "content-disposition": "0.5.3",
            "content-type": "~1.0.4",
            "cookie": "0.4.0",
            "cookie-signature": "1.0.6",
            "debug": "2.6.9",
            "depd": "~1.1.2",
            "encodeurl": "~1.0.2",
            "escape-html": "~1.0.3",
            "etag": "~1.8.1",
            "finalhandler": "~1.1.2",
            "fresh": "0.5.2",
            "merge-descriptors": "1.0.1",
            "methods": "~1.1.2",
            "on-finished": "~2.3.0",
            "parseurl": "~1.3.3",
            "path-to-regexp": "0.1.7",
            "proxy-addr": "~2.0.5",
            "qs": "6.7.0",
            "range-parser": "~1.2.1",
            "safe-buffer": "5.1.2",
            "send": "0.17.1",
            "serve-static": "1.14.1",
            "setprototypeof": "1.1.1",
            "statuses": "~1.5.0",
            "type-is": "~1.6.18",
            "utils-merge": "1.0.1",
            "vary": "~1.1.2"
          }
        },
        "finalhandler": {
          "version": "1.1.2",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/finalhandler/-/finalhandler-1.1.2.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-aAWcW57uxVNrQZqFXjITpW3sIUQmHGG3qSb9mUah9MgMC4NeWhNOlNjXEYq3HjRAvL6arUviZGGJsBg6z0zsWA==",
          "requires": {
            "debug": "2.6.9",
            "encodeurl": "~1.0.2",
            "escape-html": "~1.0.3",
            "on-finished": "~2.3.0",
            "parseurl": "~1.3.3",
            "statuses": "~1.5.0",
            "unpipe": "~1.0.0"
          }
        },
        "forwarded": {
          "version": "0.1.2",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/forwarded/-/forwarded-0.1.2.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-mMI9qxF1ZXuMBXPozszZGw/xjIQ="
        },
        "fresh": {
          "version": "0.5.2",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/-/fresh-0.5.2.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-PYyt2Q2XZWn6g1qx+OSyOhBWBac="
        },
        "graphql-request": {
          "version": "2.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/graphql-request/-/graphql-request-2.0.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-Ww3Ax+G3l2d+mPT8w7HC9LfrKjutnCKtnDq7ZZp2ghVk5IQDjwAk3/arRF1ix17Ky15rm0hrSKVKxRhIVlSuoQ=="
        },
        "http-errors": {
          "version": "1.7.2",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/http-errors/-/http-errors-1.7.2.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-uUQBt3H/cSIVfch6i1EuPNy/YsRSOUBXTVfZ+yR7Zjez3qjBz6i9+i4zjNaoqcoFVI4lQJ5plg63TvGfRSDCRg==",
          "requires": {
            "depd": "~1.1.2",
            "inherits": "2.0.3",
            "setprototypeof": "1.1.1",
            "statuses": ">= 1.5.0 < 2",
            "toidentifier": "1.0.0"
          }
        },
        "iconv-lite": {
          "version": "0.4.24",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite/-/iconv-lite-0.4.24.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-v3MXnZAcvnywkTUEZomIActle7RXXeedOR31wwl7VlyoXO4Qi9arvSenNQWne1TcRwhCL1HwLI21bEqdpj8/rA==",
          "requires": {
            "safer-buffer": ">= 2.1.2 < 3"
          }
        },
        "inherits": {
          "version": "2.0.3",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-2.0.3.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-Yzwsg+PaQqUC9SRmAiSA9CCCYd4="
        },
        "ipaddr.js": {
          "version": "1.9.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ipaddr.js/-/ipaddr.js-1.9.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-0KI/607xoxSToH7GjN1FfSbLoU0+btTicjsQSWQlh/hZykN8KpmMf7uYwPW3R+akZ6R/w18ZlXSHBYXiYUPO3g=="
        },
        "media-typer": {
          "version": "0.3.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/media-typer/-/media-typer-0.3.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-hxDXrwqmJvj/+hzgAWhUUmMlV0g="
        },
        "merge-descriptors": {
          "version": "1.0.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/merge-descriptors/-/merge-descriptors-1.0.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-sAqqVW3YtEVoFQ7J0blT8/kMu2E="
        },
        "methods": {
          "version": "1.1.2",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/-/methods-1.1.2.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-VSmk1nZUE07cxSZmVoNbD4Ua/O4="
        },
        "mime": {
          "version": "1.6.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.6.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-x0Vn8spI+wuJ1O6S7gnbaQg8Pxh4NNHb7KSINmEWKiPE4RKOplvijn+NkmYmmRgP68mc70j2EbeTFRsrswaQeg=="
        },
        "mime-db": {
          "version": "1.44.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-db/-/mime-db-1.44.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-/NOTfLrsPBVeH7YtFPgsVWveuL+4SjjYxaQ1xtM1KMFj7HdxlBlxeyNLzhyJVx7r4rZGJAZ/6lkKCitSc/Nmpg=="
        },
        "mime-types": {
          "version": "2.1.27",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types/-/mime-types-2.1.27.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-JIhqnCasI9yD+SsmkquHBxTSEuZdQX5BuQnS2Vc7puQQQ+8yiP5AY5uWhpdv4YL4VM5c6iliiYWPgJ/nJQLp7w==",
          "requires": {
            "mime-db": "1.44.0"
          }
        },
        "ms": {
          "version": "2.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/-/ms-2.0.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-VgiurfwAvmwpAd9fmGF4jeDVl8g="
        },
        "negotiator": {
          "version": "0.6.2",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/-/negotiator-0.6.2.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-hZXc7K2e+PgeI1eDBe/10Ard4ekbfrrqG8Ep+8Jmf4JID2bNg7NvCPOZN+kfF574pFQI7mum2AUqDidoKqcTOw=="
        },
        "node": {
          "version": "14.4.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/node/-/node-14.4.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-uJ9LXT9OjBEZaFtyVxSPxLfVCPZ9TPUtyqqxSyDazj2Vj40S9sL3b1hKnctktnwTG8IMqDsUnQ6HOplDS1RuMQ==",
          "requires": {
            "node-bin-setup": "^1.0.0"
          }
        },
        "node-bin-setup": {
          "version": "1.0.6",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/node-bin-setup/-/node-bin-setup-1.0.6.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-uPIxXNis1CRbv1DwqAxkgBk5NFV3s7cMN/Gf556jSw6jBvV7ca4F9lRL/8cALcZecRibeqU+5dFYqFFmzv5a0Q=="
        },
        "node-darwin-x64": {
          "version": "14.5.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/node-darwin-x64/-/node-darwin-x64-14.5.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-WoCUoKWhTia7pVCrqVziuUFJpeQd90Y2P78Nl+3tFuLMiMQQSGh7ET8JXTZHnLwUHR6UaYJ6rpsHUUnsqRiAcQ=="
        },
        "node-fetch": {
          "version": "2.6.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/node-fetch/-/node-fetch-2.6.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-8dG4H5ujfvFiqDmVu9fQ5bOHUC15JMjMY/Zumv26oOvvVJjM67KF8koCWIabKQ1GJIa9r2mMZscBq/TbdOcmNA=="
        },
        "on-finished": {
          "version": "2.3.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/on-finished/-/on-finished-2.3.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-IPEzZIGwg811M3mSoWlxqi2QaUc=",
          "requires": {
            "ee-first": "1.1.1"
          }
        },
        "parseurl": {
          "version": "1.3.3",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/parseurl/-/parseurl-1.3.3.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-CiyeOxFT/JZyN5m0z9PfXw4SCBJ6Sygz1Dpl0wqjlhDEGGBP1GnsUVEL0p63hoG1fcj3fHynXi9NYO4nWOL+qQ=="
        },
        "path": {
          "version": "0.12.7",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/path/-/path-0.12.7.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-1NwqUGxM4hl+tIHr/NWzbAFAsQ8=",
          "requires": {
            "process": "^0.11.1",
            "util": "^0.10.3"
          }
        },
        "path-to-regexp": {
          "version": "0.1.7",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/path-to-regexp/-/path-to-regexp-0.1.7.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-32BBeABfUi8V60SQ5yR6G/qmf4w="
        },
        "process": {
          "version": "0.11.10",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/process/-/process-0.11.10.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-czIwDoQBYb2j5podHZGn1LwW8YI="
        },
        "proxy-addr": {
          "version": "2.0.6",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/proxy-addr/-/proxy-addr-2.0.6.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-dh/frvCBVmSsDYzw6n926jv974gddhkFPfiN8hPOi30Wax25QZyZEGveluCgliBnqmuM+UJmBErbAUFIoDbjOw==",
          "requires": {
            "forwarded": "~0.1.2",
            "ipaddr.js": "1.9.1"
          }
        },
        "qs": {
          "version": "6.7.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/-/qs-6.7.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-VCdBRNFTX1fyE7Nb6FYoURo/SPe62QCaAyzJvUjwRaIsc+NePBEniHlvxFmmX56+HZphIGtV0XeCirBtpDrTyQ=="
        },
        "range-parser": {
          "version": "1.2.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/-/range-parser-1.2.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-Hrgsx+orqoygnmhFbKaHE6c296J+HTAQXoxEF6gNupROmmGJRoyzfG3ccAveqCBrwr/2yxQ5BVd/GTl5agOwSg=="
        },
        "raw-body": {
          "version": "2.4.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body/-/raw-body-2.4.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-4Oz8DUIwdvoa5qMJelxipzi/iJIi40O5cGV1wNYp5hvZP8ZN0T+jiNkL0QepXs+EsQ9XJ8ipEDoiH70ySUJP3Q==",
          "requires": {
            "bytes": "3.1.0",
            "http-errors": "1.7.2",
            "iconv-lite": "0.4.24",
            "unpipe": "1.0.0"
          }
        },
        "safe-buffer": {
          "version": "5.1.2",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/safe-buffer/-/safe-buffer-5.1.2.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-Gd2UZBJDkXlY7GbJxfsE8/nvKkUEU1G38c1siN6QP6a9PT9MmHB8GnpscSmMJSoF8LOIrt8ud/wPtojys4G6+g=="
        },
        "safer-buffer": {
          "version": "2.1.2",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/safer-buffer/-/safer-buffer-2.1.2.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-YZo3K82SD7Riyi0E1EQPojLz7kpepnSQI9IyPbHHg1XXXevb5dJI7tpyN2ADxGcQbHG7vcyRHk0cbwqcQriUtg=="
        },
        "send": {
          "version": "0.17.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/send/-/send-0.17.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-BsVKsiGcQMFwT8UxypobUKyv7irCNRHk1T0G680vk88yf6LBByGcZJOTJCrTP2xVN6yI+XjPJcNuE3V4fT9sAg==",
          "requires": {
            "debug": "2.6.9",
            "depd": "~1.1.2",
            "destroy": "~1.0.4",
            "encodeurl": "~1.0.2",
            "escape-html": "~1.0.3",
            "etag": "~1.8.1",
            "fresh": "0.5.2",
            "http-errors": "~1.7.2",
            "mime": "1.6.0",
            "ms": "2.1.1",
            "on-finished": "~2.3.0",
            "range-parser": "~1.2.1",
            "statuses": "~1.5.0"
          },
          "dependencies": {
            "ms": {
              "version": "2.1.1",
              "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/-/ms-2.1.1.tgz",
              "integrity": "sha512-tgp+dl5cGk28utYktBsrFqA7HKgrhgPsg6Z/EfhWI4gl1Hwq8B/GmY/0oXZ6nF8hDVesS/FpnYaD/kOWhYQvyg=="
            }
          }
        },
        "serve-static": {
          "version": "1.14.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/serve-static/-/serve-static-1.14.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-JMrvUwE54emCYWlTI+hGrGv5I8dEwmco/00EvkzIIsR7MqrHonbD9pO2MOfFnpFntl7ecpZs+3mW+XbQZu9QCg==",
          "requires": {
            "encodeurl": "~1.0.2",
            "escape-html": "~1.0.3",
            "parseurl": "~1.3.3",
            "send": "0.17.1"
          }
        },
        "setprototypeof": {
          "version": "1.1.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/setprototypeof/-/setprototypeof-1.1.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-JvdAWfbXeIGaZ9cILp38HntZSFSo3mWg6xGcJJsd+d4aRMOqauag1C63dJfDw7OaMYwEbHMOxEZ1lqVRYP2OAw=="
        },
        "statuses": {
          "version": "1.5.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/statuses/-/statuses-1.5.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-Fhx9rBd2Wf2YEfQ3cfqZOBR4Yow="
        },
        "toidentifier": {
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/toidentifier/-/toidentifier-1.0.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-yaOH/Pk/VEhBWWTlhI+qXxDFXlejDGcQipMlyxda9nthulaxLZUNcUqFxokp0vcYnvteJln5FNQDRrxj3YcbVw=="
        },
        "type-is": {
          "version": "1.6.18",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/type-is/-/type-is-1.6.18.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-TkRKr9sUTxEH8MdfuCSP7VizJyzRNMjj2J2do2Jr3Kym598JVdEksuzPQCnlFPW4ky9Q+iA+ma9BGm06XQBy8g==",
          "requires": {
            "media-typer": "0.3.0",
            "mime-types": "~2.1.24"
          }
        },
        "unpipe": {
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/unpipe/-/unpipe-1.0.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-sr9O6FFKrmFltIF4KdIbLvSZBOw="
        },
        "util": {
          "version": "0.10.4",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/util/-/util-0.10.4.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-0Pm9hTQ3se5ll1XihRic3FDIku70C+iHUdT/W926rSgHV5QgXsYbKZN8MSC3tJtSkhuROzvsQjAaFENRXr+19A==",
          "requires": {
            "inherits": "2.0.3"
          }
        },
        "utils-merge": {
          "version": "1.0.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/utils-merge/-/utils-merge-1.0.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-n5VxD1CiZ5R7LMwSR0HBAoQn5xM="
        },
        "vary": {
          "version": "1.1.2",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/vary/-/vary-1.1.2.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-IpnwLG3tMNSllhsLn3RSShj2NPw="
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So in classic fashion, I've found the solution right after posting.

I removed `"node": "^14.4.0"` from my `package.json` and it successfully built.

Answer (score 1):

came across the same issue, below commands helped fix it in my case.

```
npm cache clean
```

if that doesnt help, which in my case it didnt, then try below,

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Now try whatever you were trying, and tada! it should work!